# Best practice of sending multiple dependent transaction [solana] [web3js]

Tags: web3js, solana

what is the best practice of sending multiple dependent transaction in Solana ?
Let say i want to send 2 transaction, each are correlated.

if the second one fails then i have to ask the user to send the first and second transaction.
But actually i can implement so that when the second trx fails, it will only ask the user to retry the second one.

can someone point me the right direction on this matter?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

There's two ways to do this.

1. Pack instructions into a single transaction

If you are not bound by the transaction limitations(1232 bytes maximum, ~30 instructions max, ~18 publickeys max, 1.4m compute max), you can pack instructions into a single transaction and have any failure fail the transaction as a whole.

Example:

```js
const Transaction = new Transaction().add(
  SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: publicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: mintKeypair.publicKey,
      space: MINT_SIZE,
      lamports: lamports,
      programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  }),
  createInitializeMintInstruction(
    mintKeypair.publicKey, 
    form.decimals, 
    publicKey, 
    publicKey, 
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID)
);
```

If the above, `createInitializeMintInstruction` depends on the `createAccount` first. Packed both in a transaction, if either of the instructions fail, the entire transaction fails.

2. Manage Transaction retry on the UI

You could have each transaction separate due to limitations, but ultimately depending on each other.

```js
const transaction1 = new Transaction().add(
  SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: publicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: mintKeypair.publicKey,
      space: MINT_SIZE,
      lamports: lamports,
      programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  })
);
const transaction2 = new Transaction().add(
  createInitializeMintInstruction(
    mintKeypair.publicKey, 
    form.decimals, 
    publicKey, 
    publicKey, 
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID)
);

const signature1 = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction1, [mintKeypair, payerKeypair])
const signature2 = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction2, [mintKeyPair, payerKeypair])
```

Using the above, you can use `connection.confirmTransaction` with the signatures to verify which signatures are actually confirmed vs which failed. This will allow you to toggle the UI at will depending on which transaction is confirmed on the network.

Comment: Jacob, the said limitation (+/- 18 accounts), is it per instruction are all instructions ? (if i have 2 different instructions with 13 differents accounts and no accounts in common, will it fail ?)

Answer (score 4):

You can run multiple transactions as instructions one at a time.
For example, if you want to run tx1 and tx2, you can do like below.

```
const transaction = new Transaction();
const tx1 = await program.instruction.createPool(...);
const tx2 = await program.instruction.addFundToThePool(...);
transaction.add(tx1);
transaction.add(tx2);
const hash = await provider.send(transactions, [], { commitment: 'confirmed' });
```

Here tx1 and tx2 are not exactly transaction, but instead they are instructions and attached in a single transaction.
This way, you can run as many transactions at a time as you want. But keep in mind that there's a size limit, 1232byte as far as I know.

Comment: i knew that. my problem is that the maximum trx is only 1232 byte, what if i want to send more than that?